# Using Cocoapods with Both Objective-C and Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods

I am using a pod named CalendarLib in my project. I imported CalendarLib and typed the following code:

```
CalendarLib.checkEventStoreAccessForCalendar()
```

I got the error

```
Module 'CalendarLib' has no member named 'checkEventStoreAccessForCalendar()
```

I looked at similar questions, but none of them had a solution that worked.
I was thinking that the problem might be that checkEventStoreAccessForCalendar() is written in Objective-C but my project is in Swift. If so, how can I overcome this problem?

Comment: How do I do that if the objective-c file is not actually in my project?

Comment: Now I'm getting an error that the bridging header file doesn't exist, but it's in my project navigator

Comment: I am no longer getting the above error. However, it still gives me the original error. I tried importing a .h file from CalendarLib into the bridging header but it did not work

Comment: Yes, but it still does not work